# How to spread the philosophical word?

Tags: epistemology, education, social-epistemology

I personally think, thinking about philosophy is a very good mean to keep calm when it comes to stressful times. I know some people that don't care about philosophy at all. It's too esoteric for them, I guess. My hope is that it could help them as well to keep calm and think about their reactions before they do something, once they started to read something about philosophy.

But how can I get them on topic?

Comment: What is a soft question? Did you check for similar question that have been asked and answered already?

Comment: @iphigenie see [Soft-questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) at Math.SE. Which posts would you recommend?

Comment: I didn't know that concept, and there is a reason why there was no soft-question tag before you introduced it - that is simply not the kind of questions that we're looking for. Quite the contrary - we are specifically looking for questions that can be answered.

Comment: @iphigenie you don't think the question can be answered? How sad...apropos: Did you downvote?

Comment: This does seem like a concern more appropriate for meta or chat as it stands...

Comment: @Joseph where's the main difference to this question: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/9189/1127 ?

Comment: It's a little unclear exactly what's being asked here. I'm not sure it's reasonable to demand people "get on topic" with whatever you happen to consider "philosophy" -- but that said, again, it seems like maybe meta or chat might be a more appropriate forum for these sorts of non-technical problems...

Comment: This question does not appear to be about philosophy within the scope defined in the help center. It is also too broad and I imagine all the answers will be purely opinion-based since I can't imagine any scientific studies have be done to investigate which method of spreading "the philosophical word" is most effective.

Comment: **Duplicated by https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/39711 and https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/45838.**

Answer (score 1):

Realize who will listen. There are crossed-armed-people and lay-people. This relates to past experiences with philosophy or their nearest [Stage of Ego Development](http://www.stillpointintegral.com/docs/cook-greuter.pdf).

1. [Is the Socratic Method is the best way to teach philosophy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9264/is-the-socratic-method-is-the-best-way-to-teach-philosophy)
2. [Are the unexamined lives of others worth examining?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/138/are-the-unexamined-lives-of-others-worth-examining)
3. [Why is philosophy viewed as unnecessary, extra, by the common man?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9189/why-is-philosophy-viewed-as-unnecessary-extra-by-the-common-man)

Comment: This question is _of_ philosophy, not _about_ it. The help center defines this as, "[too informal](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic);" yet, the Cognitive Science SE is not a better option. Agree, should be meta or chat. Why wasn't it posted there in the first place?