# Is everyone able to learn philosophy? If not, what kind of person is able to learn philosophy?

Tags: logic, ethics, epistemology, ontology

Is everyone able to learn philosophy?  If not, what kind of person is able to learn philosophy?

Does learning philosophy require a certain intelligence or talent? If I start at the age of 18, is it too late?

I am a student of vocational high school, majoring in informatics engineering.
I rarely read books other than textbooks, and just recently read a non-textbook book titled *Sophie's World*. That is what led me to this question.

Comment: Try with some introduction, like e.g. Craig's [Philosophy: A Very Short Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=Q1GrPvK2B_UC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: [This question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-is-philosophy) has been asked multiple times already here, you should always try to search for your question to make sure it hasn't been asked before. None of the answers (in my opinion) on that question are particularly great answers, but the community decided that "what is philosophy" is not a good question for this site. If you really want just an answer to that question, try reading something like [this](https://www.brown.edu/academics/philosophy/undergraduate/philosophy-what-and-why).

Comment: Or Nagel's [What Does It All Mean?: A Very Short Introduction to Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=Nz_XMrjBQEUC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Also useful some book on phil's history, like Scrution's [A Short History of Modern Philosophy: From Descartes to Wittgenstein](https://books.google.it/books?id=3SVo_TZ5uKEC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: [Asking for introductions to philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/4248/what-are-some-good-introductions-to-philosophy) has also already been done. No, you're not too old to start learning, but like I said, you should use the search feature on the site to make sure your question hasn't already been asked.

Comment: You might want to find this book used:  Man is the Measure by Rueben Abel. https://books.google.com/books/about/Man_is_the_Measure.html?id=OllFClD68swC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button

Comment: Or this book used by Julian Marias:  https://www.google.com/search?q=julian+marias+history+of+philosophy&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us&client=safari#imgrc=isvNO3TlC2E5dM:  Whatever book you choose you should plan to read it at least three times in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe also: Duncan Pritchard (editor), [What is this thing called Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=7YD_CwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Routledge (2015)

Comment: Hi @Didil, welcome to Philosophy SE!  I thought your question was good, but needed some editing to clarify your main point.  I removed a lot of material, and rearranged it, but I tried to stick with your own words.  If you don't like the way I edited it, please feel free to revert the edit.

Answer (score 2):

First, age 18 certainly is not too late to start philosophy.  Most people do not start studying philosophy until college or later, and no less an authority than the ancient Greek philosopher Plato recommended that philosophy be reserved for adults (to avoid confusing children morally).

In my opinion, anyone can learn philosophy, but in my experience, most people do not enjoy it.  You need a questioning mind, and a certain openness to strange and unfamiliar ideas.  Many very smart people are not comfortable with this.

The original definition of the word "philosophy" is "love of wisdom," and I would argue that loving philosophy (not having a certain IQ or talent) is the main prerequisite for studying it successfully.  Having an good grasp of logic definitely helps a lot, but that is a learnable skill.

Answer (score 1):

It might be argued that everyone should be forced to study philosophy to a certain level but as to whether everyone can learn it this is another question. It is clear that the vast majority of professional are unable to do so.

What kind of person can learn it? I'd say one who is curious, at least averagely intelligent, scrupulously honest, loves reading and thinking, is a little arrogant, is an iconoclast, has the courage to follow the logic wherever it leads, is good at self-study, is too lazy to study theories that do not work and who is reluctant to go anywhere near a university philosophy course.

Age eighteen is not too late, nor is age seventy-eight. Philosophy is like a musical instrument, it's never too late to derive some benefit from studying it. if you mean study to become a professor then eighteen is probably just in time, but if you mean study so that you come to some understanding then the pressure is off and you can start anytime. The former task is enormous, the latter more manageable. For me it was age fifty, so plenty of time yet.